# how to disable edit link of node view page of drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to disable or hide edit link for specific role on node view page.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the role does NOT have *administer nodes* permission
2. Also make sure the role does not have `edit any <content type> permission` & `edit own <content-type>` where  is the content type you want to disable editing for.

I would also suggest you pickup a decent book on Drupal -- it will teach you the fundamentals. I'm guessing you're reasonably new to Drupal.